# Is Shift the only key that can change the value of keyCode?

Tags: javascript, keycode

I am writing some javascript to handle keyboard input. At one point in my code, I make the assumption that `keyCode for keyPress event != keyCode for keyDown event` if and only if the shift key is being held down.

Is this a correct assumption? Or are there other keys where this condition holds? Specifically, I'm concerned about alternate keyboard layouts such as AZERTY and QWERTZ.

Comment: What about the CTRL and ALT keys?

Comment: It helps to provide the actual code you wrote

Comment: The code I wrote shouldn't impact the answer to this question. It's a general question about how keyCodes work in JavaScript.

Comment: @Brandon it is part of SO rules that you post what have you tried. It helps narrow down the possible answers to a generic question. In your case it is so broad that some would have voted to close it. Please see if my answer below is of any help.

Comment: @amenadiel I disagree that my question was broad. I simply asked whether a specific statement is true, and any code that I have written has no impact on the truth value of that statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assumption is wrong. You see, the `keydown` event is fired whenever you press a key. The `keypress` event is fired only when said key outputs a printable character.

That being said, pressing a key between `a` and `z`, for example "a" will generate:

1. `keydown` with keyCode 65 (A)
2. `keypress` with keyCode 97 (a)

So they are not equal for the general case. Whereas pressing "SHIFT + a" will generate:

1. `keydown` with keyCode 16 (Shift)
2. `keydown` with keyCode 65 (A)
3. `keypress` with keyCode 65 (A)

So they are equal when the shift key is being pressed down.

For the numeric keys the behavior is inversed. Pressing "1" will generate

1. `keydown` with keyCode 49 (1)
2. `keypress` with keyCode 49 (1)

So they are equal without pressing the Shift key, whereas pressing "SHIFT+1" will generate:

1. `keydown` with keyCode 16 (Shift)
2. `keydown` with keyCode 49 (1)
3. `keypress` with keyCode 33 (!)

So they are not equal when Shift key is pressed.

Having CAPS LOCK ON, will set the letters to uppercase by default, so keyCodes will be equal for `keydown` and `keypress`. CAPS LOCK won't affect numerical keys, so they will still have equal keyCodes for `keydown` and `keypress`.

Other event modifiers such as CTRL, ALT, and the combination of them with SHIFT, won't generate printable characters, so while a `keydown` event will be triggered, no `keypress` event will fire.

I made a small [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/amenadiel/rp3s31do/) to compare the events. I added a bit of extra logic to pair the events when keypress and keydown are fired at once.